# Using deductive reasoning to prove a true statement with false premises?

Tags: logic

Using the fact that

$$ A \vDash B ~~~~ \text{iff} ~~~~ \vDash (A \implies B) $$

What if I take $A := (1=2)$ and $B := (1=1)$ Then we have that:

$$ \vDash (1=2) \implies (1=1) $$ Which is $$ \vDash \mathbb{T}$$ as $A = \mathbb{F}, B = \mathbb{T}$ thus $\mathbb{F} \implies \mathbb{T} := \mathbb{T}$

And so we get that:

$$ (1=2) \vDash (1=1)$$

What have I done here? this sounds like nonsense... how can you prove $1=1$ starting from $1=2$ (?!)

Thank you!

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, what you have done is both correct and nonsense. If you start with a false assumption, you can prove *anything*. You can prove true statements, false statements, contradictory statements, independent statements, *anything*. That is why we prefer to avoid false assumptions in our proofs.

Comment: Sounds ok to me lol, but how can we really prove that $1=1$ from $1=2$ or it is "trivially true" cus... $1=1$ so it doesn't matter if we started from $1=2$ or $1=\text{elephant}$ am I correct?

Comment: I think you just need to separate in your mind the two concepts of what is "true" and what is "provable". We generally think that provable statements are true, but this is based on the assumption that we have only true hypotheses/axioms. What you can prove is what follows from your logical rules given your hypotheses. Indeed, using standard logical rules, you can directly prove any statement from a false one. See the "Principle of Explosion" as a commenter mentions.